# How to get granular privacy control per Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, twitter

Facebook offers [privacy](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy) control over apps, so I decided set up the [Twitter](http://apps.facebook.com/twitter) application to post updates to my wall.

But I would also like not to let everyone see these updates (that would be annoying), I have set the privacy for the apps in the Game and app activity section, yet when I tested it, the post still showed as set to "Friends". Twitter is a Facebook application but it also acts an update right?

So which settings should I be using to control just Twitter updates on my wall for specific people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter updates go to your wall at the default level of privacy for wall posts. I think the people who created the Twitter app are responsible for adding the granularity for the privacy.

However, it doesn't matter, because the Twitter app **cannot** read your Twitter updates and repost them to Facebook unless your Twitter posts are public in the first place - public as in **anyone** can see them.

Comment: My Twitter profile is indeed public but no one will know it is there unless I tell the Twitter handle. Everyone can see the tweets if they really wanted to, my point is *that I rather not push it into their newsfeed every time I update, I rather do it to a select bunch.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the recent changes to Facebook's layout this now appears to be possible.  From the main page there should be an arrow pointing down to the far right.  Clicking on this arrow you can select the 'Account Settings' menu option.  This should take you to a new page which includes on the right a link called 'Apps', go ahead and click on this.  Scroll through your apps until you find Twitter and then hit the edit button.  You should see a variety of options including, down at the bottom, the ability to customize exactly who gets to see messages from the app.

Hope this helps.